# Compiling on an ARM Emulator for use on an Android Phone

Tags: android, c, arm, shared-libraries

so I'm trying to compile a program on an ARM emulator (Quem and the laungauge is C) for use on an Android phone. This is because I can't get build-essentials and/or cmake on my android phone, but I do have Terminal Emulator and Busybox.

Anyways, I compiled the program last night (Took forever!) and when I tried to run it on Android today It was originally saying Permission Denied (Even though I have SU), I found out that it was because I need to have it as executable, but since the sdcard was a FAT32, I wasn't able to use chmod. So I mounted /system, and copied over the binary to there after chmod 777'ing it. And now it gives me ./myprogram: not found even though it is clearly there.

Doing some reading, people are saying it could mean there are missing libraries, but Android doesn't have the ldd command so I don't know how to find out what it's missing. Also, might be a game breaker, but I found out that my phone is on an ARMv7 where as the emulator is ARM926EJ-S will this make a difference?

Any input is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I makes little sense (IMHO) to compile on the emulator. It makes more sense to use a cross compiler to build your application and its dependencies. Please search for info on using the NDK.

Comment: Unless the library you're compiling requires it to be done on the target. I can think of two libraries where this is necessary because it needs to check the targets characteristics at compile time.